# "ghc --make site.hs" encounter error

Tags: haskell

root@AR:/usr/local# git clone https://github.com/CleverCloud/clever-cloud.com

root@AR:/usr/local# cd clever-cloud.com

root@AR:/usr/local/clever-cloud.com# ghc --make site.hs

[1 of 4] Compiling Utils ( Utils.hs, Utils.o )

[2 of 4] Compiling CustomTags ( CustomTags.hs, CustomTags.o )

[3 of 4] Compiling RouteFactories ( RouteFactories.hs, RouteFactories.o )

[4 of 4] Compiling Main ( site.hs, site.o )

site.hs:192:26: error:
Ambiguous occurrence ‘defaultTimeLocale’

It could refer to either ‘Data.Time.Format.defaultTimeLocale’,

imported from ‘Data.Time.Format’ at site.hs:10:1-33

(and originally defined in ‘time-1.6.0.1:Data.Time.Format.Locale’)

or ‘System.Locale.defaultTimeLocale’,

imported from ‘System.Locale’ at site.hs:12:1-30

root@AR:/usr/local/clever-cloud.com#

how to fix it?

Tks

Comment: Mark your code. Perhaps list things you've tried to investigate?

Answer (score 0):

Replace defaultTimeLocale with System.Locale.defaultTimeLocale or Data.Time.Format.defaultTimeLocale, depending on which you're using.

Comment: hi,@ Manmeet Gill, i Replace defaultTimeLocale with Data.Time.Format.defaultTimeLocale,this time, i ran "ghc --make site.hs" successfully. but after i ran "./site build",it shows: " [ERROR] Hakyll.Core.UnixFilter.unixFilterWith: lessc - --yui-compress -O2 gave exit code 1", how to fix it?tks